# How to know in Objective C if a message is already sent to the rabbitmq server?

Tags: rabbitmq

I am using rabbitmq client (https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-objc-client). I wanted to notify whether or not a message is sent to the rabbitmq server, but I couldn't find anything related to whether or not the message is really sent.

Could someone tell me how to know if I publish a message to a queue and the message really arrives to the rabbitmq server?. Thanks in advance !

Kinh

Answer (score 0):

[Publisher acknowledgments](http://www.rabbitmq.com/confirms.html) are on the amqp level, handled by RMQ itself. In the "API" level you may get a exception or a return value or some indication  depends on the library.

Quote from the aforementioned link:

> For unroutable messages, the broker will issue a confirm once the
>   exchange verifies a message won't route to any queue (returns an empty
>   list of queues). If the message is also published as mandatory, the
>   basic.return is sent to the client before basic.ack. The same is true
>   for negative acknowledgements (basic.nack).
>
> For routable messages, the basic.ack is sent when a message has been
>   accepted by all the queues. For persistent messages routed to durable
>   queues, this means persisting to disk. For mirrored queues, this means
>   that all mirrors have accepted the message.

Comment: Thank you! I will try if I could receive something.